# Javascript Recussion Error - RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

Tags: javascript

i have a recursion that is going to this error **RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded**

Recursion function

```
window.traverse_all_sublogins = (flat, LOGIN) => {
    let sublogins = [LOGIN];
    if (flat[LOGIN] && flat[LOGIN].children) {
        let children = flat[LOGIN].children;
        for (let i of children) {
            sublogins = sublogins.concat(traverse_all_sublogins(flat, children[i]));
        }
    }
    return sublogins;
};
```

**flat equal as below**

```
{
"account_1": {"login": account_1, "parent": "account_2", "path": [],"children": ["account_3", "account_4"]}
"account_5": {"login": account_5, "parent": "account_6", "path": [],"children": ["account_7", "account_8"]}
}
```

**LOGIN equal as below**

```
account_1
```

by going in my recursion is going to this error **RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded**, will appreciate any help.

Thanking in advance

Comment: This does mean your function is called too many times. Is there any cycle loop in your data ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that this is CoffeeScript. This works:

```
traverse_all_sublogins = (flat_login_table, login) ->
  sublogins = [login]
  if login of flat_login_table
    for child in flat_login_table[login].children
      sublogins = sublogins.concat(traverse_all_sublogins(flat_login_table, child))
  return sublogins
```

I don't know from where you took `account_1` and `account_5` that are in `flat` as variables, so I changed them to strings for my testing purposes. Similarly I don't know from where you took `isEmpty`, so I used CoffeeScript's way + I don't care if children list is empty since iterating over empty iterable works by doing nothing.

I suggest better names than "login" and "flat" or "LOGIN". Did you mean usernames and aliases? Is flat a whole DB table that you traverse by hand in JS? You can write this function in SQL if so. Also please use explicit "return" when writing multiline code, it's more readable this way.

Comment: thanks @Ctrl-C the if statement did the job, finally my recursion got fixed, thanks for help

Comment: about account what u said, the data is not formed on the backed, this is coming from DB data and inside children can be anything, and from this children using recursion i am creating a tree who is under who and so on

Answer (score 0):

Although this doesn't really look like javascript, if it were javascript, this is probably what you'd be looking for.

Also maximum call stack probably means you infinitely calling traverse_all_sublogins recursively, probably because your if statement is only protecting the first line and not the for loop.

```
window.traverse_all_sublogins = (flat, LOGIN) => {

    var sublogins = [LOGIN];
    if (!isEmpty(flat[LOGIN].children)) {
      var children = flat[LOGIN].children
      for (var i of children) {
        sublogins = sublogins.concat(traverse_all_sublogins(flat, children[i]))
      }
    }
    return sublogins;
}
```